# C++20 Concept should only work for numbers but not chars

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Can someone explain how char datatype is supported by AdditionFeasible concept in below code snippet and how we can prevent that and ensure that it only works for numbers ?

```
template< class T >
concept AdditionFeasible = requires(T& f, T& s) 
{
    f + s;
};

template <AdditionFeasible f>
f sum(f a, f b)
{
    return a + b;
}
int main()
{
    std::cout<<"sum of 2 and 3 is "<<sum(2,3)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"sum of 'K' and 'V' is"<<sum('K','V')<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Characters are numbers. We use it all the time in constructions like `ch - '0'`.

Comment: Agree that internally characters are numbers but is there any way to differentiate between them and ensure that function should only work for real numbers otherwise throw meaningful error

Comment: Characters are as not unreal. They are just numbers (not "internally" but in every sense of the word) . Addition and all other operations make perfect sense for them.

Comment: You can exclude `char` (or any other type you want) with `require !std::same_as<char>` or whatever the syntax is, but it is arbitrary and capricious.

Answer (score 2):

STL has a type trailt `is_arimethic` to ensure the type is number only as well as avoid unexpected types which are non-numerical types. The `char` type is a special one we also treat it as number. The only way is to exclude it explicitly

```
template< class T >
concept AdditionFeasible = std::is_arithmetic_v<T> && ! std::same_as<T, char> && requires(T& f, T& s) {
   f + s;
};
```

Comment: probably want to remove `unsigned char` and `signed char` too

Comment: @Caleth That would remove `int8_t` and `uint8_t` too, though.

Comment: @Bob__ either of those might be removed by removing `char`, it's implementation defined

Comment: @Caleth To my understanding (which may very well be wrong), the signness of  `char` is implementation defined, but `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` should be [different types](https://godbolt.org/z/dYEheYess).

Comment: @Bob__ yes, but nothing says that `int8_t` has to be an alias for `signed char` and `uint8_t` an alias for `unsigned char`, one of them could be an alias for `char`